# Orthonormal basis of linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

For a rectangular matrix $M_{i\mu}$ where $i=1,...,m$ and $\mu=1,...,n$ and $n>m$, consider the following $n-m$ dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbf{R}^n$:
$$V=\{\vec x\in \mathbf{R}^n:M\vec x=0\}.$$
Clearly $V$ is spanned by $n-m$ orthonormal vectors $\{\vec e_1,...,\vec e_{n-m}\}$. How can one find an explicit set of such vectors given $M_{i\mu}$?

Comment: The standard way is to find any basis using row reduction, say, and then apply Gram–Schmidt to that basis. Is there a reason that won't suffice for your purposes?

Comment: You need $M$ to be of rank $m$ for $V$ to be of dimension $n-m$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! I think the basis is also the set of eigenvectors of $M^TM$ with zero eigenvalue -- which seems like an easier thing to compute.